# dlls in VS code (c++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I recently switched to working with VS code.
Its actually doing a great job so far,
but there is one thing that annoys me: how do I add libraries in c++?
really I have tried every thing.
that's an example of (trying) to add the SFML library:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "g++",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "suppressTaskName": true,
    "tasks": [
        { 
            "taskName": "Compilation",
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "args": ["-c", "${workspaceRoot}\\main.cpp", "-IC:\\SFML-2.4.2\\include"]
        },
        { 
            "taskName": "Execution",
            "args": ["${workspaceRoot}\\main.o", "-o", "sfml-app.exe", "-LC:\\SFML-2.4.2\\lib", "-lsfml-graphics", "-lsfml-window", "-lsfml-system"]
        }
    ],
    "showOutput": "always"
}
```